# How to get clicked-on filename as argument of shell script triggered by this mouse-click

Tags: bash, mouse, arguments

If, in Ubuntu's Nautilus, I click a midi-file, a window opens to specify an application for processing the file. Another option is a "user generated command" (UGC). (Let me choose Ubuntu, Nautilus, midi and bash for example). I know how to play midi files in the terminal using timidity, so I hope I can set up a bash script **playmidi** (example) for that purpose.

1. However, I do not know how to get the filename as a script parameter. If possible, this "mouse parameter" should go together with "ordinary" fixed ones for timidity.
2. What syntax has to be used in the UGC?
3. If UGC space allows, can I insert the timidity command directly, but once more, how do I refer to the file?

Answer (score 0):

your script would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/timidity "$1"
```

But, can you right-click the midi file and "open with" timidity instead? Seems simpler.